# SQL многие-ко-многим

Tags: sql, база-данных

В руководствах по проектированию `БД`как и в офф документации показаны примеры проектирования связи `many-to-many` через промежуточные таблицы.

Ситуация c авторами и книгами. книга может быть написано несколькими авторами, автор может написать несколько книг.

Ниже прилагаю пример кода

```
CREATE TABLE books
( 
    book_id integer NOT NULL,
    book_name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE autors
( 
    autor_id integer NOT NULL,
    autor_name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE book_autor
( 
    book_id integer NOT NULL,
    autor_id integer  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id , autor_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books,
    FOREIGN KEY (autor_id ) REFERENCES autors,
);
```

Вопрос в том, почему в промежуточной таблице `PRIMARY KEY` (book_id , autor_id ). Это ведь приводит к отношению 1-к-1?

Куда логичнее было бы

```
   CREATE TABLE book_autor
    ( 
        id integer NOT NULL,
        book_id integer NOT NULL,
        autor_id integer  NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books,
        FOREIGN KEY (autor_id ) REFERENCES autors,
    );
```

Но такого в документации нет. Как все таки правильно работает пример из документации в связях `many-to-many`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Абсолютно логичная структура. Она не приводит к связи один к одному. Допустим у нас есть книги с id 1, 2, 3 И авторы с id 100, 101, 102

Pramary key не позволит вставить в таблицу book_autor дважды запись (1,100). но он позволит заполнить ее так:

```
book_id  autor_id
1        100
1        102
2        101
2        102
3        100
3        101
3        102
```

Таким образом у нас связь многие-ко-многим. Книгу 1 написали авторы 100 и 102. Автор 100 написал книги 1 и 3.

А структура с отдельной колонкой id и primary key по ней позволит нам создать записи:

```
id  book_id  autor_id
 1    1       100
 2    1       100
 3    1       100
```

Что будет видимо означать, что автор 1 написал книгу 100 три раза. Т.е. такая структура таблицы не сможет нам обеспечить участие одного автора в написании одной книги только один раз.

Comment: Понятно я не подумал, что PK на двух столбцах может повторяться в одном если он отличается в строке в другому.  Перед закрытием вопроса, прошу уточнить. В пример так же еще фигурирует что делаются не только внешние ключи, но так же еще и добавляется индексы на поля промежуточной таблицы, Для чего это нужно если поля PK? Вопрос возник потому что это дефолтное построение таблицы при миграции для создание промежуточных таблиц. Зачем там индекс? Только для скорости выборки или есть еще какой-то сакральный смысл?

Comment: У разных СУБД требования для foreign разные. Обычно требуется только parimary что бы на него мог смотреть foreign. на связочной таблице индексы - да, в первую очередь для обеспечения скорости выборки. Но, надо помнить, что при удалении записи из books БД должна проверить что в book_autor не осталось записей с ее id, она это быстрее сделает по индексу. Конечно на book_id я бы отдельный индекс делать на стал, т.к. он первым полем в primary, по нему найдет. на autor_id можно (а для некоторых СУБД нужно) сделать

Comment: Если индекс уникальный на промежуточной таблице по нескольким полям, то он может выполнять роль ключа и не позволять создавать дублирующие записи

Comment: Так PK в промежуточной таблице и так не даст создавать промежуточные записи