# Добавить в одно поле несколько значений из другой таблицы, sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Постараюсь описать ситуацию
У меня есть таблица с пользователями и в ней поле факторов и таблица с несколькими факторами. Можно ли их как-то связать так, чтобы можно было присвоить одному пользователю несколько факторов, сохранив это всё в одно  поле? Чтобы под каждый фактор не создавать отдельное поле.
Я конечно не уверена, но это можно сделать связью М:М и доп. таблицей?

Comment: Да, это так и делается. Это не "можно сделать связью М:М", это является связью М:М. В доп таблице должны быть обязательно два столбца - id пользователя и id фактора

Comment: По сабжу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490910/sql-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC

Comment: Хранение нескольких значений в одном поле (CSV) - плохая практика. Такие данные очень плохо обрабатываются, ибо не индексируются - т.е. каждый запрос будет порождать фуллскан таблицы. *это можно сделать связью М:М и доп. таблицей?* Нужно.

Comment: Ага, поняла. Может есть какой либо другой вариант решения?

Comment: Зачем искать другой способ, когда уже есть один - хороший, высокопроизводительный, проверенный временем и кучей народу?

Comment: Нет, я не против данного способа, просто мне говорили, что он достаточно ресурсоёмкий

Answer (score 1):

Сохранение нескольких значений в одно поле является нарушением [первой нормальной формы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) реляционной модели. Реляционные СУБД, чтобы называться реляционными должны не позволять ее нарушать.

Так что прямой ответ - нет, нельзя.

И вообще как только в постановке задачи возникает слово "несколько", значит речь идет о таблице.

В вашем случае - о дополнительной таблице связей М:М

**PS** Существуют способы обхода ограничения, например, преобразовав некоторое количество свойств в одну длинную строку (CSV, XML, JSON...), но они замедляют как разработку так и работу БД